# How to pass a number parameter from a properties file to a Spring annotation number (long, or int, or Integer, etc) parameter

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I try to pass a number value from the Spring properties file to Annotation long properties and I wonder how to set correctly non-string parameter. I try to use the following way, and obviously, we cant define parameters with strings because of `Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.String', required: 'long'`

And my question is "How to pass a number parameter from a properties file to a Spring annotation number parameter"

**application.properties**

```
my.parameter=10
```

**MyAnnotation.java**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface MyAnnotation {

    long myParameter() default 0;
}
```

**MyClass.java**

```
@Component
@MyAnnotation(myParameter = "${my.parameter}") //incompatible types long and String
public class MyClass {

//some code
}
```

Comment: One way would be to define 2 properties in your annotation - long and String. If String is defined, it overrides long. You need to parse String - as you havent specified how you process your annotation, it is difficult to recommend a class to do it - `ConfigurableBeanFactory` and `ConfigurableEnvironment` come to mind. You can even go full monty and support SpEL in String param. Check `org.springframework.retry.interceptor.Retryable` for similar approach with `maxAttempts` and `maxAttemptsExpression`.

Comment: @Lesiak thank's a lot for a bunch of ideas. I`ll check it in my code too. Your help is very appreciated and your answer really valuable to me

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt will fail early at compilation phase (so, not at runtime where Spring resolves application properties), because the template (`"${my.parameter}"`) is a string, not a long (as expected by the definition of the annotation class `MyAnnotation`).

A solution would be to change the type of myParameter to `String`, and then resolve it (when needed) using an autowired `ConfigurableEnvironment` from Spring.

For example:

```java
@Component
@MyAnnotation(myParameter = "${my.parameter}")
public class FooComponent
{
    @Autowired private ConfigurableEnvironment env;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initialize()
    {
        MyAnnotation a = FooComponent.class.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
        // resolve using our application properties
        String s = env.resolvePlaceholders(a.myParameter()));
        // convert to long
        long n = Long.valueOf(s);
        // use n somehow ...
    }


    // ... more methods ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer I had asked another question, not about the error. I would like to find some way to pass int parameter

Comment: @OlegUshakov, i have added an example of resolving a property in a programmatic manner

Comment: I don't want to change the parameter type. We can use e.g. int in the case when we define it as constant, e.g. @MyAnnotation(myParameter = 10) but what about variables from the property file? Do you know a way to use it for int parameter in the example?

Comment: @OlegUshakov, i am not sure i understand the question. If you want to autowire values from application properties you can just use `@Value("${my.parameter}") private int myParameter` as a member of the `@Component` class

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple options that might work:

1. `@MyAnnotation(myParameter = "#{ T(java.lang.Long).parseLong('${email.config.port}')}")`
2. Change the value in application.properties to `my.parameter=10L`.

If you get the `NumberFormatException` after this - it means that Spring was not able to find the property.

References & useful sources:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66084308/9899739
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40894656/9899739
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27341777/9899739
4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52064355/9899739
5. [docs.spring.io, Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config)

Comment: Also I think I should mention that normally Spring is more than capable to convert such values. This options are supposed to be considered only when that's not the case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The construction looks so bulky but it seems we still don't have any new mechanics for automated type conversion in this case. Anyway I have some idea based on your answer and  I wanna check it now

Comment: how your solution (1) will even compile (given that `myParameter` is long)?